# I have two large lists and I need get the diff between them

Tags: c#, performance, list, linq, loops

I have two large lists and I need get the diff between them.

The first list is from another system via webservice, the second list is from a database (destiny of data).

i will compare and get items from first list that not have in second list and insert in the database (second list source).

have another solution with best performance?

using `List.Any()`, the process take a lot of hours and not finish...

using `for` loop, the process take 10 hours or more.

Each list have 1.300.000 records

```
newItensForInsert = List1.Where(item1 => !List2.Any(item2 => item1.prop1 == item2.prop1 && item1.prop2 == item2.prop2)).ToList();

//or
for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
{
    if (!List2.Any(x => x.prop1 == List1[i].prop1 && x.prop2 == List1[i].prop2))
    {
        ListForInsert.Add(List1[i]);
    }
}

//or
ListForInsert =  List1.AsParallel().Except(List2.AsParallel(), IEqualityComparer).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: How large are your lists? Something that fits into your RAM should never take "hours" just to find out it's identical to another object.

Comment: Either show your code or post a [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for us to understand better.

Comment: How large is large? Let us know what the count is for both lists. It actually matters. You're using a very naive, simplistic approach, utilizing only a single thread. Of course it will take hours...!!!  Also, the nature of the lists themselves matter. The manner of comparison will differ depending on if they are strictly orthogonal, or not.

Comment: code added, please, see

Comment: Any progress on this? There must be something *not* related to the list difference algorithm (whichever you use) that's causing the exceptionally long execution time.

Answer (score 4):

You could use List.Except

```
List<object> webservice = new List<object>();
List<object> database = new List<object>();
IEnumerable<object> toPutIntoDatabase = webservice.Except(database);

database.AddRange(toPutIntoDatabase);
```

EDIT:

You can even use the new PLINQ (parallel LINQ) like this

```
IEnumerable<object> toPutIntoDatabase = webservice.AsParallel().Except(database.AsParallel());
```

EDIT:

Maybe you could use a Hashset to speed up lookups.

```
HashSet<object> databaseHash = new HashSet<object>(database);

foreach (var item in webservice)
{
    if (databaseHash.Contains(item) == false)
    {
        database.Add(item);
    }
{
```

Comment: i try using Except too, but not solve my problem, take a long time in processing.

Comment: I have edited the answer, maybe a lookup table could help?

Answer (score 1):

If same data type then you can use List.Exists,

Else Better to go with inner join and emit

```
var newdata = from c in dblist
join p in list1 on c.Category  equals p.Category into ps
from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

it will select list if given data not present in dblist

Comment: you know how can use 2 conditions in 'equals' ?

Answer (score 1):

[`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) is optimized for executing this kind of set operations. In many cases it's worth the effort to create HashSets from Lists and do the set operation on the Hashsets. I demonstrated this with a little Linqpad program.

The program creates two lists containing 1,300,000 objects. It uses your method to get the difference (or better: *attempted to used*, because I ran out of patience). And it uses LINQ's `Except` and hashsets with `ExceptWith`, both with an `IEqualityComparer`. The program is listed below.

The result was:

```
Lists created: 00:00:00.9221369 
Hashsets created: 00:00:00.1057532 
Except: 00:00:00.2564191 
ExceptWith: 00:00:00.0696830
```

So creating the HashSets and executing `ExceptWith` (together 0.18), beat `Except` (0.26s).

One caveat: creating HashSets may take too much memory since the large lists already take a fair amount of memory.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var amount = 1300000;
    //amount = 50000;
    var list1 = Enumerable.Range(0, amount).Select(i => new Demo(i)).ToList();
    var list2 = Enumerable.Range(10, amount).Select(i => new Demo(i)).ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("Lists created");
    sw.Restart();


    var hs1 = new HashSet<Demo>(list1, new DemoComparer());
    var hs2 = new HashSet<Demo>(list2, new DemoComparer());
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("Hashsets created");
    sw.Restart();

//    var list3 = list1.Where(item1 => !list2.Any(item2 => item1.ID == item2.ID)).ToList();
//    sw.Stop();
//    sw.Elapsed.Dump("Any");
//    sw.Restart();

    var list4 = list1.Except(list2, new DemoComparer()).ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("Except");
    sw.Restart();
    hs1.ExceptWith(hs2);
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("ExceptWith");

//    list3.Count.Dump();
    list4.Count.Dump();
    hs1.Count.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Demo
{
    public Demo(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = id.ToString();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class DemoComparer : IEqualityComparer<Demo>
{
    public bool Equals(Demo x, Demo y)
    {
        return (x == null && y == null)
            || (x != null && y != null) && x.ID.Equals(y.ID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Demo obj)
    {
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, running the program with 50000 items your method took 17 seconds.

Comment: Maybe your best option is to obtain the lists as Hashsets right away so you don't have to convert them to Hashset any more. However, I'm surprised to see your comment that Except is also very slow. I'm starting to suspect that during the Except operation massive lazy loading is triggered. Could you provide details of the actual objects involved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `List.Exists`, it is better than `List.Any` **Performance-wise**

Comment: MSDN says: "This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count." for List.Exists. You reckon Enumerable.Any is somehow doing worse than that? :D